# KeyError in Plug connection or session

Tags: session, connection, elixir, phoenix-framework

So I was getting the error below because I was trying to access the `:id` key. No surprise here. However, my actual question is why is the user placed inside the `:session` key? Is this Plug specific? I don't remember setting user to the key `:session` as you can see in the view below.

Error:

```
** (KeyError) key :id not found in: 
%{
  session: %ExampleApp.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    email: "ka@example.com", 
    first_name: "keith", 
    id: 356, 
    inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-25 00:56:51>, 
    last_name: "a.", 
    updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-25 00:56:51>, 
    username: "keith"
  }, 
  view_module: ExampleApp.SessionView, 
  view_template: "show.json"
}
```

View that caused error:

```
defmodule ExampleApp.SessionView do
use ExampleApp.Web, :view

def render("show.json", %{jwt: jwt, user: user, exp: exp}) do
  %{
    jwt: jwt,
    exp: exp,
    user: render_one(user, __MODULE__, "show.json")
  }
end

def render("show.json", user) do
  %{
    id: user.id, #<------------------------------------------ HERE
    username: user.username,
    last_name: user.last_name,
    first_name: user.first_name
  }
end
```

I had to do the following to access the user's information:

```
...

def render("show.json", user) do
  %{
    id: user.session.id, #<------------------------------------------ HERE
    username: user.session.username,
    last_name: user.session.last_name,
    first_name: user.session.first_name
  }
end
```

Here's the controller if it helps:

```
defmodule ExampleApp.RegistrationController do
use ExampleApp.Web, :controller

alias ExampleApp.{Repo, User, SessionView}

def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.new_changeset(%User{}, user_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      {:ok, jwt, claims} = user |> Guardian.encode_and_sign(:token)
      exp = Map.get(claims, "exp")

      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> render(SessionView, "show.json", %{jwt: jwt, user: user, exp: exp})

    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render("error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, my actual question is why is the user placed inside the `:session` key?

That's because `render_one` tries to guess the key name using the name of the view you passed. In this case, you passed `SessionView`, so the key to use for the model is inferred to be `:session`. If you instead want it to be in `:user`, you can pass `as: :user`:

```
def render("show.json", %{jwt: jwt, user: user, exp: exp}) do
  %{
    jwt: jwt,
    exp: exp,
    user: render_one(user, __MODULE__, "show.json", as: :user)
  }
end
```

You can read more about this in the [documentation for Phoenix.View.render_one/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_one/4).

> ...
>
> ```
> render_one user, UserView, "show.html"
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The underlying user is passed to the view and template as `:user`, which is inflected from the view name. The name of the key in assigns can be customized with the `:as` option:
>
> ```
> render_one user, UserView, "show.html", as: :data
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert for the fast reply! I totally skimmed over that section of the docs. Silly me.